# What is this type of hinge - and how do I remove it?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges

I'm looking into refurbishing an old kitchen, and encountered a problem I hadn't expected: I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the hinges from the cabinets. The hinges look as follows (excuse the scuff marks):

| Hinge (door mounted) | Cabinet side | Door side (w/ pin) | Inside of cabinet side |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Picture of mounted hinge] | [image: Picture of cabinet hinge] | [image: Picture of door side w/ pin] | [image: Inside of cabinet side of hinge] |

Both the cabinet and the cabinet door is made out of wood.

The door side is simple enough to remove: twisting it counter-clockwise reveals that it [internally consists of a screw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Elsa.jpg). But since the cabinet side consists of two attachments, I am unable to turn it similarly! Another hinge of the same type goes through the side of another cabinet, showing [a pair of screws in the back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce9JY.jpg) (but no obvious way to unscrew them).

The hinge has evidently been painted over a few times as tenants have come and gone, making it harder to see - but as far as I have been able to detect, there are no screws or plates accessible to use for unscrewing the hinge.

I now turn to you: what kind of hinges are these, and how am I best to remove them from the cabinets? It is not required, but preferred, that the hinges be kept intact for future re-installation.

(location is in northern Europe, if relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those look like [welded hinges](https://alcobrametals.com/product/steel-weld-on-2-36/). It looks like threaded rods have been stud welded to them. You would remove your hinges with an angle grinder. If you cut the thing in half between the two anchor points, then you can unscrew each half.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that. I tried [scratching off a bit of paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf5Tl.jpg) (from the [door side too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWCrp.jpg)), and although the welds are unusually nice to my inexperienced eye, I don't see any other way these could be attached.

Comment: @Birjolaxew, they could be threaded from the back. If the door was glued together and it's mounted to a face frame, then I could easily imagine screw heads installed behind glue. In that case, though, the solution is still the angle grinder (or rehabbing the hinges).

Comment: Think of this as your opportunity to add soft-close hinges?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Looks like you pound them in with a hammer. So they're removed with a hammer. Problem is, now they *won't go back in with a hammer*. Leave them alone unless you can find nuts that go on there.